# Rails create multiple instances if title is null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a create action in one of my controllers which will update a submission if it finds one in the system with the same title as the one being created. However, if the title is null I'd like it to create new instance anyway.

The piece of code looks like this:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(title: ajax_title)
```

So if it finds a instance of the Submission model with the same title as the one being created, it'll just update the current one instead of creating a new instance. However, I'd like to go ahead and create new instances if the user didn't input a title, regardless of if there are any other Submissions in the system with a null title.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a judgement about whether the query result is blank or not:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(title: ajax_title)
@submission = Submission.create if @submissions.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to just add another line that only creates a new submission if the title is blank:

```
@submissions = Submission.where(title: ajax_title)
@new_submission = Submission.create if ajax_title.blank?
```